# angular2-datatable Not able to update data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, typescript, datatable

After the datatable once get rendered , I am not able to update data.
I am using angular2-datatable.

In my appcomponent.html:

If I update data2 in my appcomponent.ts file like this:

```
this.httpservice.getdata().subscribe
(data=>
{   this.data2=data;
    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    markerarray[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.data2[i].latituide, this.data2
    [i].longituide),          //In this line
    title: this.data2[i].name,  //and this
    map: map
    });
        }
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {

            var bounds = map.getBounds();
           for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var marker = markerarray[i];
           if (bounds.contains(marker.getPosition()) === true) {
            this.data2.length=0;// This is not working for me
            }
            }

        });
 })
```

I want to empty the datatable once the markers are in bound.

Comment: try to do this.data2=[]

Comment: Use `arrow function` to retain `this` instead of `function {`

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova I tried this. But it is still not updating :(

Comment: @yurzui I tried using the fat arrow function. But the table is still not updating.

Comment: if u comment all code inside http subscribe and just do this.data2= [], does it work? show u binding to datatable.

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova Thank you! Yes ,I did that.I figured out the solution. I used ChangeDetectorRef  for detecting changes every 5 seconds. Now the table is updating when bounds change.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution , though I am not sure that this is the best way.

I have used ChangeDetectorRef for detecting changes.

```
  constructor(private http: Http,private httpservice: HttpService,private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
       ref.detach();
    setInterval(() => {
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    },1000);
    }
```

Comment: It might hurts performance of your app doing detectChanges every second. Also you need to remove interval in OnDesctroy - otherwise memory leak.

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova Oh okay. Do you have any other solution in mind? I am not able to figure out anything else.

Comment: I use datatable a lot and i am able to modify push changes. If you belive that you have an issue with change detection try to do " setTimeout(() => {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
      });" after you changed data2.